# C++ check std::array or unordred_map/map contain same element type

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, types, unordered-map

I have a templated class accepting a container of `MyIDType`:

- `std::array<MyIDType, SIZE>`
- `std::unordered_map<A, MyIDType>`
- `std::unordered_map<B, MyIDType>`
- etc

I'd like to statically-assert for `MyIDType` being the element. I tried this:

```
template<class CONTAINER>
class Cod
{
    using ELEMENT_TYPE = typename CONTAINER::value_type;
    static_assert(std::is_same<ELEMENT_TYPE, MyIDType>::value);
```

but realised it'd fail because the value type of `std::unordered_map` is actually an `std::pair<something, MyIDType>`

What is the best way to check for `MyIDType` for both `std::array` and `std::unordered_map`?

The map has `mapped_type` but obviously this won't compile when I pass-in the array.

Comment: Are you going to support just two container types?

Comment: `if constexpr` or more long or-expression in the static assert.

Comment: @SergeyA yes just those two, but the map's key type could change.

Comment: And you want `std::unordered_map::mapped_type`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a type trait like

```
// primary template, for types containing value_type
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct get_element_type {
    using type = typename T::value_type;
};
// partial specialization, for types containing mapped_type
template <typename T>
struct get_element_type<T, std::void_t<typename T::mapped_type>> {
    using type = typename T::mapped_type;
};
```

then

```
template<class CONTAINER>
class Cod
{
    using ELEMENT_TYPE = typename get_element_type<CONTAINER>::type;
    static_assert(std::is_same<ELEMENT_TYPE, MyIDType>::value);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xyCXWcH9hj9XydvJ)

Comment: Will this work with cpp17? I'm getting an error on using type = typename T::value_type; It expects an expression where 'using' is

Comment: @user997112 Sorry, I missed an `>`, answer revised. And yes, `std::void_t` requires C++17. If your compiler doesn't support C++17 you can make your own substitute.

Comment: No apology needed! So the line 'using type'', is that actually being "returned" to the call using ELEMENT_TYPE = typename get_element_type?

Comment: @user997112 Yes, it's used to define a nested type, then we can use it like `get_element_type<...>::type`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve what you want. The easiest (provided you only have two types) seems to be through helper struct:

```
template<class CONTAINER>
struct ElementType {
    using type = typename CONTAINER::mapped_type;
};

template<class T, size_t SZ>
struct ElementType<std::array<T, SZ>> {
    using ElementType = T;
};
```

And than you can assert on ElementType. There are other ways as well, which allow to selectively use `mapped_type` or `value_type` based on presence of `mapped_type`, but since you mentioned you only need two, it seems an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to check for MyIDType for both std::array and std::unordered_map?

You can use template specialisation of a type trait:

```
template<class Container>
struct fancy_element_trait {
    using type = typename Container::value_type;
};

template<class ... Args>
struct fancy_element_trait<std::unordered_map<Args...>> {
    using type = typename std::unordered_map<Args...>::mapped_type;
};
```